# The exponential term in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Given the differential equation

$P = \frac{L}{De^{-mt} + 1}$,

an intial population of 1000, $L = 10000$ and $m = 0.003$, find the number of years it will take for the population to triple.

To solve this, I thought it would make sense to start with

$1000 = \frac{10000}{De^{-0.003t}+1}$,

giving

$De^{-0.003t}=9$.

But that still leaves me with two unknowns.

However, the given answer begins with

$1000 = \frac{10000}{D+1}$,
$D=9$,

then shows the remainder of the values substituted in,

$3000=\frac{10000}{9e^{-0.003t}+1}$,

$t=450$ years.

How we are able to ignore $e^{-mt}$ to find $D=9$, as shown in the given answer?

Comment: Set $t=0$ maybe

Comment: What does "initial population" mean? When was that measured? The answer is $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not a differential equation but, at the most, only the last step of solution of a differential equation, where you must use the initial condition to find a constant. In tis case tis constant is $D$ and te inital condition is that for $t=0$ $P=1000$. So you have to put these values in the equation and find $D$.